# How to give a specific computers read and write access to a share folder on Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, network-shares, shared-folders

I had a folder on Windows Server 2016 that needed to be shared with about 12 computers in a local network. How can I setup the folder permission so that only two specific accounts from two specific computers (say \Computer1\User1 and \Computer2\User2) have read and write permission to the folder, and all other computers have only read permission to the folder?

Comment: Do you use Active Directory, or are the computers standalone (workgroup mode)?

Comment: I think the computers are standalone.

Answer (score 0):

When you access a network share, Windows first tries to log in using the same details as the local account (if that doesn't work, it prompts for login details). The server then uses its own account database to authenticate the user, just like it would for console or Remote Desktop logins, and all access checks are made against that account.

Most importantly, access is granted to **user accounts**, not to computers. If you grant read/write access to the username "FredFoobar", then that user can get read/write access from *anywhere*, as long as they know the correct password.

(Note: Active Directory in Server 2012 feature level (or higher), appears to have a feature called "Claims" which would probably make combined [user, computer] access rights possible. But because this is built on top of Kerberos, it requires AD.)

---

So if you don't use Active Directory, first create matching accounts (same username, and *maybe* the same password) on the server, for every person who will be accessing the share.

Then open the shared folder's "Properties → Security" tab, change the default "Users" permissions to read-only, and grant the modify right to User1 and User2. (You may have to disable inheritance under the "Advanced" screen at first.)